# Splitting column with numeric value into separate rows in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an R dataframe that contains a rather large number of length measurements.

It is structured as follows:

```
> head(rb.len)
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  Length  Year Value Total Perc_Distr
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1    9.5  1981     1 16641          0
2   10.5  1981     3 16641          0
3   12.5  1981     3 16641          0
4   13.5  1981     4 16641          0
5   14.5  1981    17 16641          0
6   15.5  1981    31 16641          0
```

Individuals of a certain length are grouped together and the total number of individuals (n) of a length class is listed in the column "value" (e.g. 17 individuals of 14.5cm were measured). For my further analysis I need each measurement to be in a separate row (so basically I need 17 rows with a measurement of 14.5cm). Unfortunately all I have learned so far is how to split columns with  observations with multiple delimited values. As I have a single numeric value I am unsure how to proceed.

Hope you can help,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SO. Could you provide a dput() please. : dput(rb.len)

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and, in particular, the part about providing input in reproducible form.  I have done it for you this time in the Note at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) tidyr** Using `rb.len` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, use `uncount` as shown.  Add the argument `.remove=FALSE` to `uncount` if you prefer to retain the `Value` column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

rb.len %>% uncount(Value)
##   Length other
## 1    9.5     a
## 2    9.5     a
## 3   10.5     b
## 4   10.5     b
## 5   10.5     b
```

**2) Base R** Using base R we have the following.  Replace `, ]` with `, -2]` if you prefer to omit `Value` from the output (because in `rb.len` shown in the Note `Value` is the second column).

```
rb.len[rep(1:nrow(rb.len), rb.len$Value), ]
##     Length Value other
## 1      9.5     2     a
## 1.1    9.5     2     a
## 2     10.5     3     b
## 2.1   10.5     3     b
## 2.2   10.5     3     b
```

### Note

```
rb.len <- data.frame(Length = c(9.5, 10.5), Value = 2:3, other = letters[1:2])

rb.len
##   Length Value other
## 1    9.5     2     a
## 2   10.5     3     b
```

Comment: So sorry for not providing a reproducible input, it is definitely noted for future questions! And thank you so much for your help. This was much easier than anticipated!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood you correctly. There is a nice solution that repeats the whole rows n-times:

```
rb.len<- as.data.frame(lapply(rb.len, rep, df$Value))
```

If you wish to multiply only some columns:

```
rb.len<- as.data.frame(lapply(rb.len[1:2], rep, df$Value))
```